# Installation of amdgpu fails - packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, dependencies, radeon, amdgpu

I'm trying to install amdgpu according to the instructions found here: https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html

Running the command:
`sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation  --accept-eula`

gives the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-pro : Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext but it is not going to be installed
```

I am trying to install amdgpu because my second monitor is undetected and it seems that I don't actually have a driver installed as my output for `sudo lshw -c video` is:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:2f:00.0
   version: c1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcdfffff memory:fce00000-fce1ffff
```

I would expect the driver to be listed by configuration if there was one installed.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Full output for amdgpu-install:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                         
Hit:4 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.50.2/ubuntu focal InRelease                                          
Hit:5 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.0.2 ubuntu InRelease                                                
Get:6 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.50.2/ubuntu focal/proprietary amd64 Packages [3,562 B]
Get:7 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.50.2/ubuntu focal/proprietary i386 Packages [2,884 B]      
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]               
Fetched 342 kB in 1s (275 kB/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]              
Hit:4 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.50.2/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Hit:6 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.0.2 ubuntu InRelease
Fetched 336 kB in 1s (643 kB/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic is already the newest version (5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1).
linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic set to manually installed.
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic is already the newest version (5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-pro : Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]              
Hit:4 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.50.2/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Hit:6 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.0.2 ubuntu InRelease
Fetched 336 kB in 1s (642 kB/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                             
Hit:4 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.50.2/ubuntu focal InRelease                                               
Hit:5 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.0.2 ubuntu InRelease                                                     
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 0s (677 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

The solution simply installing libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext
```